# C - prompt user for valid int causes endless loop when input is not an int

Tags: c, scanf

```
int main(void) {
  int x;

  do {
    printf("Height: ");
  } while(!((scanf("%d", &x)) == 0) && !(x > 0 && x < 23));

}
```

I want to simply prompt a user to enter a number between 0 and 23, and if the input is invalid (not an int or out of range), I want to prompt again until they do it right. However, the first time I enter an invalid integer, I get "Height" printed over and over again in an endless loop. How can I prompt them until it the input is valid?

It works when I enter a number out of range, but not when I enter a string like "abc"

Comment: I very much doubt you are getting "Hello" printed over and over again in an endless loop from *this fragment of code*... Where would "Hello" come from?!

Comment: My mistake. At first I was prompting hello, and then changed it to 'Height'. Just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` will return 1 if, and only if, the user has inputted something that can be converted into an `int`.

If `scanf` does not return 1, then it's your job to clear the stream so another value can be read in. You do that with the idiomatic

```
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

It's this second thing you are not doing that appears to be causing your code to print endlessly.

There are more succinct ways but this is a starting point:

```
int main(void) {
    int x;    
    do {            
        printf("Height: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1){
            // invalid input, clear the stream and go round again.
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
            continue;
        }
   } while (x < 0 || x > 23);
   return x;
}
```

(Some folk don't like an empty `while` loop written in the way I have. Adjust accordingly if it's not to your taste: some firms ban it.)

Comment: You may also want to treat an `EOF` return value from `scanf` differently, as that would cause an infinite loop of a different kind.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your truth statement. It should probably be something like `while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1 && (x < 0 && x > 23))`. `scanf` returns the number of variables it successfully assigned.[<sup>#</sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html#tag_03_190_04)

But I recommend you read the value of inside the loop statement itself and not the truth statement. It's just hard to reason about when it it's in the truth statement and you've fallen into a pitfall doing that.

Comment: But that's the opposite of what I want. I only want to prompt the user again when scanf is not 1 and x is not less than 23

Comment: @killer_manatee you're right. I changed it. should be obvious

Comment: Part of the problem here is that when `scanf` fails to read input, that input is left on the stream... and I do believe OP wants to discard that invalid input and retry, so even though this answer is good, I can recommend modifying it to branch off into the circumstances when `scanf` returns 0 (which does indeed involve extracting the `scanf` from the loop control expression); you can discard the invalid input like so: `scanf("%*[^ \n]");`.

Comment: See the part where OP writes *"I want to simply prompt a user to enter a number between 0 and 23, and if the input is invalid (not an int or out of range), I want to prompt again until they do it right."* for clarification...

Comment: Also worthy of reading would be a newsgroup post on the topic written by Chris Tourek (IIRC) which I can't seem to find...